# How to resolve: "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function"

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-mix, sweetalert2

Inside my Vue Component. I have a method (show) that shows sweetalert2 input message. But it returns an error after using laravel mix (npm run watch)

```
show(){

    const { value: email } = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Input email address',
    input: 'email',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
    })

    if (email) {
        Swal.fire('Entered email: ' + email)
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure exactly the calling syntax you have for the show method, but you need to declare that function as `async` in order to use `await`.

For example, in a module method:

```
const show = async () => {
  const { value: email } = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Input email address',
    input: 'email',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
  })

  if (email) {
    Swal.fire('Entered email: ' + email)
  }
}
```

As an instance method in a class:

```
class MyComponent {
  async show() {
    const { value: email } = await Swal.fire({
      title: 'Input email address',
      input: 'email',
      inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
    })

    if (email) {
      Swal.fire('Entered email: ' + email)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async show(){ 
   //here
    const { value: email } = await Swal.fire({
        title: 'Input email address',
        input: 'email',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
    });

    if (email) {
        Swal.fire('Entered email: ' + email);
    }
}
```